# Почему нельзя сразу запустить конкурс?

Tags: обсуждение, конкурс

Я на мете не часто появляюсь, так что извиняйте если повтор.
Есть допустим важный вопрос и хочется за его решение объявить конкурс, но это разрешается только через 2 дня...

Comment: в течении первых двух дней вопрос и так увидят большинство активных пользователей, отслеживающих интересующие вас метки. 
Соответственно, Ваш вопрос и так получит достаточно внимания. 
Если к этому еще добавить конкурс, то это будет не очень честно по отношению к вопросам,  которые были заданы ранее и уже вышли из зоны видимости большинства пользователей.
Зачем отнимать внимание и конкурировать с вопросами, которые не могут получить внимание другим способом?

Comment: Всем хочется получить ответ на вопрос прямо здесь и сейчас. Размер минимальной награды очень маленький. Если с таким размером дать возможность всем назначать конкурсы, то на этой вкладке может начаться настоящая вакханалия и свалка из-за чего данная вкладка может потерять весь свой смысл. Регулировать это можно размером минимальной награды. Но тогда пользователи с небольшим количеством репутации могут лишиться возможности получить ответы на свои воросы. Выбирая между возможностью сразу же публиковать конкурс и демократичной ценой - лучше последнее, как мне кажется.

Comment: Ну и стоит понимать, что при возможности публиковать конкурс сразу могут появиться желающие данных механизмом злоупотреблять (Особенно с текущей ценой)...я про рекламу и пр.

Comment: Также если мне не изменяет память - конкурс сложнее закрыть силами рядовых участников. Поэтому нужно какое-то время на его проверку силами сообщества.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Просто хотелось разъяснений.